# Rails: How to pass flash from one helper to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-flash

Hi I have a rails helper for collecting flash messages in engine X

```
def flash_messages
  message = []
  flash.each do |k,m|
    message << m
  end
  message
end
```

Now I have overridden this function in my main app helper

```
include X:Xhelper

def flash_messages
  message = []
  if required_message
    flash.each do |k,m|
      message << m
    end
  else
    message = "Flash messages are not displayed"
  end
  message
end
```

Now when I use this, I get the error **"undefined local variable or method `flash' for Object:Class"** which comes because flash is not defined for helper.

Thanks

Comment: can you answer it, one who voted it down.

Comment: You haven't asked a question; that's likely why you were down-voted.

Comment: As for the errors, look in your `flash_messages` methods; neither defines a `flash` method or variable, thus the error.

Comment: Define how the flow will happen then you will answer your question.

Comment: @Deefour See the tharrison answer below, don't downvote if you have no idea of the question, flash is present in the context of the request, thanks

Comment: I didn't down-vote you - I was merely speculating why you were down-voted, as your Question is poorly worded & presented (thus why it was closed out by the community). Further, I explained to you what the cause of your error was as @tharrison did - `flash` is not a defined method or variable accessible by the methods in your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails `flash` is present in the context of a request, and is managed internally using part of the session.  So a method that references flash must be in that context, in other words a controller.  Rails helpers are, by default, available in views only, not controllers.  If you move your method to ApplicationController, then it should have access to the flash.

Here's the [Rails documentation on `flash`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)